# importing MPI kills kernel (using Python 3.5.2, Spyder IDE)

Tags: mpi, anaconda, spyder

I recently installed mpi4py for Python 3 (specifically 3.5.2, running IPython console on Spyder IDE).  I can import the package, however immediately after I run the command, "from mpi4py import MPI," the kernel crashes and I get the following message, printed repeatedly: "It seems the kernel died unexpectedly.  Use 'Restart kernel to continue using this console."

Obviously there is an issue with importing MPI, but I'm not sure how to figure out what the particular issue is, and how I can fix it.  If anyone has had experience with this problem and knows a fix, I'd much appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you import the package in a regular Python console?

Comment: No, actually, in the regular console I'm getting this error:

[[28809,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file orted/pmix/pmix_server.c at line 262.

I actually found a similar error on MPI.org and they state "The workaround for the Open MPI 2.0.x and v2.1.x release series is to set the TMPDIR environment variable to /tmp or other short directory name."

So, I'm able to import MPI running Python 3 in the terminal after I do the following: export TMPDIR=/tmp.  I'm not really sure why or what this code does, but it still doesn't work within Spyder regardless.